# Bash string continuation for MySQL command

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to clean up a database while running some tests in a bash script, and the following attempt at line continuation is not working:

```
mysql -e "DELETE FROM test.users WHERE username ="\
            "'<a href=https://localhost>XSS Hack!</a>';"
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'web'@'localhost' to database ''<a href=https://localhost>XSS Hack!</a>';'
```

The command works fine if I run it on a single line.

Comment: @SeanBright That works, thanks! So I guess we can always use an implicit line continuation inside a string?

Answer (score 1):

The backslash escapes the newline, but the whitespace at the beginning of the next line still acts as a word delimiter. So the command becomes equivalent to:

```
mysql -e "DELETE FROM test.users WHERE username =" "'<a href=https://localhost>XSS Hack!</a>';"
```

If you end a line in the middle of a string, you don't need to escape the newline. MySQL doesn't mind newlines in queries, either. So you can simply write:

```
mysql -e "DELETE FROM test.users WHERE username =
          '<a href=https://localhost>XSS Hack!</a>';"
```